# too many parameters returned by Resolver.ModuleName

Tags: go, graphql

I am working on breaking the monolithic architecture into Microservice architecture.
I did that but when I am building the code in my current repository I am getting this error.

We use graphql-gophers library

`panic: too many parameters returned by (Resolver).Dummy`

Has anyone ever seen this error in golang using graphql for querying?

Tried so many things but nothing has worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message comes from [`graph-gophers/graphql-go` `internal/exec/resolvable/resolvable.go#makeFieldExec`](https://github.com/graph-gophers/graphql-go/blob/aa1669172f4f88fe73e1eda6d571c183ff5a5efa/internal/exec/resolvable/resolvable.go#L303-L339)

It is called when you parse a schema which does not match the field of an existing struct.

The one illustrated in [`example/customerrors/starwars.go`](https://github.com/graph-gophers/graphql-go/blob/aa1669172f4f88fe73e1eda6d571c183ff5a5efa/example/customerrors/starwars.go) does match every field and would not trigger the error message:

```golang
var Schema = `
    schema {
        query: Query
    }
    type Query {
        droid(id: ID!): Droid!
    }
    # An autonomous mechanical character in the Star Wars universe
    type Droid {
        # The ID of the droid
        id: ID!
        # What others call this droid
        name: String!
    }
`

type droid struct {
    ID   graphql.ID
    Name string
}
```

[Its resolver](https://github.com/graph-gophers/graphql-go/blob/aa1669172f4f88fe73e1eda6d571c183ff5a5efa/example/customerrors/starwars.go#L43-L50) does use the right parameters:

```golang
type Resolver struct{}

func (r *Resolver) Droid(args struct{ ID graphql.ID }) (*droidResolver, error) {
    if d := droidData[args.ID]; d != nil {
        return &droidResolver{d: d}, nil
    }
    return nil, &droidNotFoundError{Code: "NotFound", Message: "This is not the droid you are looking for"}
}
```

Try and use that example to check it does work, then modify it to transition to your own code.

Comment: We use graphql-gophers library, if anyone has used this library and came across similar issue. Kindly respond.

Comment: @SharoonAustin OK, that would have been helpful to include in your question.

Comment: @SharoonAustin I have edited/rewritten the answer accordingly.